# Jquery Plugin sayCheese not recording properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, codeigniter

I'm having problems recording a image. On the DB it shows as fotos-foto.bin (Binary).

I'm using Codeigniter and a jquery plugin, I'm able to acess the camera, take the picture, but it is not recording properly.

Any thoughts?

Here is my code

VIEW

```
  <html>
<head>
    <title>WebCam</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <style type="text/css">

        #content{
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 1000px;
            position: relative;

        }

        .fotografia{
            width: 320px;
            height: 240px;
            border: 20px solid #333;
            background: #eee;
            -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
            -moz-border-radius: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 50px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;

        }

        .marca {
            z-index: 2;
            position: absolute;
            color: #eee;
            font-size: 10px;
            bottom: -16px;
            left: 152px;

        }

        #obturador,#guardarFoto{
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid;
            background-color: #444;
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-left: 50px;

        }


    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div style="float:left;width:50%">
            <div id="webcam" class="fotografia">
                <span class="marca">tutoriales.com</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:50%">
            <div id="say-cheese-snapshots" class="fotografia">
                <span class="marca">Snapshots</span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>

        <div style="float:left;width:50%">
            <span id="obturador">Tomar foto</span>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;width:50%">
            <span id="guardarFoto">Guardar Foto</span>
        </div>

        <div class="fotografia">
            <img id="fotoGuardada" src="" style="display:none" />
            <span class="marca">Foto Armazenada</span>

        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/say-cheese.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var img=null;
       var sayCheese = new SayCheese('#webcam',{snapshots: true});

       sayCheese.start();

       $('#obturador').bind('click', function(e){
           sayCheese.takeSnapshot(320,240);
           return false;
       });

     sayCheese.on('snapshot', function(snapshot){
           img = document.createElement('img');

           $(img).on('load', function(){
               $('#say-cheese-snapshots').html(img);
           });
           img.src = snapshot.toDataURL('image/jpg');
       });

        $('#guardarFoto').on('click', function(canvas){
         var src = img.src;
         alert("#guardarFoto clicked!");
         data = {
             src: src
         };
         $.ajax({
             url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>webcam/ajax',
             data: data,
             type: 'post',
             sucess: function(respuesta) {
                 $('#fotoGuardada').attr('src', respuesta).show(500);
             }
         });
        });


    </script>
</body>
```

CONTROLLER

```
  <?php

class Webcam extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model(array('Fotos_model'));
}


public function index() {
        $this->load->view('webcam/index_view');
    }

    public function ajax () {
        $src = $this->input->post('src');
        $this->Fotos_model->gravarFoto($src);
        $foto = $this->Fotos_model->getLastFoto();
        $this->output->set_output ($foto);

    } 
}
```

MODEL

```
  <?php

class Fotos_model extends CI_Model{

public function gravarFoto($foto) {
    return $this->db->insert('fotos',array('foto'=>$foto));

}

public function getLastFoto() {
    return $this->db->order_by('id','desc')->get('fotos')->row()->foto;

}
}
```

Comment: you want to upload the image??

Comment: No, i'm acessing the camera, taking a picture, sendind to the DB and show the picture someplace else.